# Covering compact convex $-C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ with $x+dC$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$: counterexample?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

From Matousek's Lectures in Discrete Geometry:

> Let $C$ be compact convex in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Prove that there is a suitable translation of $C$ blown up by a factor of $d$ which covers the reflection of $C$; that is, show there is an $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $-C \subseteq x + dC$.

I am confused by this question. Consider the following:

[image]

Then the reflection of this $C$ will be oriented in a different direction than $C$, and I don't see how it blown up by a factor of $2$ will make it able to cover $-C$. The greatest vertical distance between points in $2C$ is $20$, while the greatest vertical distance of between two points in $-C$ is $110$.

Am I misunderstanding the question? Or is this a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think that the greatest vertical distance between two points in $-C$ is $110$; it should just be $10$, same as $C$.

Here is a diagram showing a scaled copy of $C$ overlaid on $-C$:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is at the heart of why I'm confused about the question: if $-C = \{-x : x \in C\}$, then the point $(10,40)$ in $C$ is sent to $(-10,-40)$ in $-C$. Continuing with this process, we can see that $-C$ is $C$ reflected *about the origin*. So if $C$ is oriented horizontally in this picture, $-C$ is oriented vertically. If the question said a translation *and rotation*, I would not be confused, but I don't know how cover this $-C$ with only a translation of $2C$.

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion! $-C$ looks like $C$ rotated by $180^\circ$, not $90^\circ$. Try actually plotting the negations of the vertices in $C$, i.e., $(-10,-40), (-120,-40)$, and $(-120,-50)$. You'll see that they form a horizontally-oriented triangle.

Comment: Oh, duh. I see I was just confusing myself. Thanks for the help, and on my other question too!